# Help with citation (in text, in parentheses etc.) with biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

My working Example:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{Wortpaare}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Basically I need 3 different citations in the text:

> A. "wie Meier und Müller (2003) sagten."

with german "und" instead of "and" or "&" in the text (works with `\textcite`).

> B. "was klar ist (Meier & Müller, 2003)."

with "&" in parentheses (works with `\parencite`).

> C. "was klar ist (Meier & Müller, 2003, Kap. 4)."

with an additional reference in parentheses like page or chapter.

Right now for C. I write

```
"was klar ist (`\cite MeierMüller2003`, Kap. 4)."
```

with the usual `\cite`command without parentheses, which I manually put around this phrase.
But then I get

```
"was klar ist (Meier und Müller, 2003, Kap. 4)."
```

with the german "und" instead of the desired ampersand.

Also, for a second citation of three or more authors f. e. with `\textcite` I need the "et al.", but I am getting the german "u. a." right now.

I am really confused at the moment about what language to put in `\DeclareLanguageMapping` and the babel package in general (I need english for an english Abstract after the german abstract - code for that upon request). But I think neither language will solve my C. citation problem above.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: For C you should use `\parencite[Kap.~4]{MeierMüller2003}`. For `et al.` you need to modify the `.lbx` file or override the strings in the preamble.

Comment: Thank you for the first advise! I don't understand which strings in the preamble you mean or where that file is and in which way I should modify it, though. I am only a LaTeX-beginner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For citations as in C, you could write `\parencite[Kap.~4]{testart}` or `\parencite[5]{testart}` (see examples below).
Note that you should use the citation macros with curly braces, so use `\cite{MeierMüller2003}` *not* `\cite MeierMüller2003`.

---

To change the `andothers` string from `u. a` to `et al.`, you need to edit the localisation strings. Just put the following two lines after `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` in your document.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  andothers ={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  andmore   ={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}
```

---

*Alternatively*, you can create a file with the following content and save it under `ngerman-apaed.lbx` in the directory your `.tex` document is located.

```
\ProvidesFile{ngerman-apaed.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman-apa}% extras are inherited from ngerman ...
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {ngerman-apa},% .... as well as all the keys
  andothers        = {{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
  andmore          = {{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
}
```

You then modify the line `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` to  `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apaed}`.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  andothers ={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  andmore   ={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testartlong,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter and Rita Esearcher and Steven C. Ientist and Stuart Udent and Peter R. Ofessor and Lewis E. C. Turer},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {8},
  number        = {2},
  page          = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
}
@article{testart,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor and William Riter},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journal       = {Journal of Articles},
  volume        = {7},
  number        = {3},
  page          = {1-5},
  date          = {2010},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
}
@online{testonline,
  author        = {Bernie Logger},
  title         = {A Very Opinionated Blog Post},
  url           = {http://example.com},
  year          = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \verb|\cite{testart}| & \cite{testart}\\
    \verb|\textcite{testart}| & \textcite{testart}\\
    \verb|\parencite{testart}| & \parencite{testart}\\
    \verb|\parencite[Kap.~4]{testart}| & \parencite[Kap.~4]{testart}\\
    \verb|\parencite[15]{testart}| & \parencite[15]{testart}
  \end{tabular}

  \parencite{testartlong} and \parencite[5]{testbook}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit

For multiple citations within one pair of parentheses use `\parencites` or `\parencite`.
`\parencites(Herzkreislauf;)()[34]{testartlong}[Kap.~4]{testbook}` yields `(Herzkreislauf; Uthor et al., 2010, S. 34; Ordsmith, 1983, Kap. 4)`; `\parencites[Pre][Post]{testartlong,testbook}` gives us `(Pre Ordsmith, 1983; Uthor et al., 2010, Post)`.

See also sections 3.7 to 3.7.6 of the [BibLaTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)